# В чем разница между live-server и http-server?

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер, npm, spa

Когда задался вопросом запуска SPA Angular на компьютере.
Я нагуглил, что самый простой способ запустить скомпилированную версию это с помощью какого-нибудь сервера. Нагулил, что это можно сделать с помощью [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) или [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) или [lite-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) и вроде как еще с [webpack-dev-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-dev-server)

Я почитал и понял, что lite-server это обертка над [browsersync](https://browsersync.io/). Browsersync может отслеживать изменения файлов и обновлять при этом браузер, а lite-server еще перенаправлять запросы на index.html, что как раз и жизненно необходимо для нормальной работы SPA (по крайней мере Angular приложению с PathLocationStrategy).

Как я понял, webpack-dev-server это по сути тот же browsersync, который срабатывает сразу после сборки файлов.

Почитал readme live-server и http-server и мне показалось, что это почти клоны, которые отличаются лишь названием передаваемых при запуске аргументов.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить в чем между ними разница и зачем появился live-server, если до него уже был http-server (судя по version history этих пакетов на npmjs)?

P.S.
На вопрос "какой из них лучше использовать", я так думаю ответ - http-server, потому что он чаще обновляется, а значит чаще исправляются баги, так?

Comment: В справке live-server чётко написано не использовать его на продакшене

Comment: Использовать http-server тоже нет никакого смысла, потому что все его задачи может выполнить nginx

Comment: @andreymal, я и не собирался использовать их на продакшене. Я на своем компе делаю приложение на Angular7 и когда захотел запустить скомпилированный код пришлось искать способ запустить все это и тогда появился этот вопрос.

Comment: Ну лично я на своём компе тоже использую nginx для этого)

Comment: Angular без CLI используете?

Comment: @KonstantinFedorov, естественно вместе с CLI, про `ng serve` я знаю. Просто когда захотел запустить скомпилированный после `ng build` проект, понадобился сервер и возник выше изложенный вопрос.

Comment: @Drovosek ну тогда действительно, проще всего использовать nginx.